# Apple Script Keynote Auto-Loop

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, keynote, iwork

Hello I'm trying to build a very simple Automator service to automatically turn on Auto Loop within a Keynote document. I'm not a very familiar with AppleScript, but I have used it a few times to do minor things. I'm gettin the following error when using this script within an automator service:

**Synatax Error**

"Can’t set «class aulp» to true."

Im sure it is something very obvious, but I'm not that well versed in AppleScript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script

```
on run {input}
set thisDocument to input
tell application "Keynote"

    tell thisDocument

        set auto loop to true



        save thisDocument

    end tell

end tell
end run
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the workflow document is set up in Automator? What are the "Service receives selected ... in" popup menus set to?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but you can not `save thisDocument of thisDocument` (double reference).